# Dynamic home link for OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

For example in Wordpress you can call to home with:

```
<?php echo home_url(); ?>
```

But in OpenCart I can't find a similar function. In my header this works:

```
<?php echo $base; ?>
```

But not on other templates in my theme. Someone who got a global function for this in OpenCart? Or a library to share, would be perfect!

I work with OpenCart 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller of the page, in my case footer.php I pasted this:

```
if ($this->request->server['HTTPS']) {
$server = $this->config->get('config_ssl');
} else {
$server = $this->config->get('config_url');
}

$data['base'] = $server;
```

And then in my template, footer.tpl I could use:

```
<?php echo $base; ?>
```

Comment: This is not going to respect your SEO urls. If you just wanted to link to `http://yoursite.com/` why not just use `/`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<?php echo HTTP_SERVER; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this in OpenCart is to use

```
<?php echo $this->url->link('common/home'); ?>
```

Note that this adds the full URL and route, not just `/` which is not possible using the SEO URL class without modification

Comment: Ah missed the 2.0 reference. You'll need to either set the variable in the controller, or use a pretty hackish method of `<?php global $url; echo $url->link('common/home'); ?>` in your template (not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'); ?>
```

Comment: How so Mr SVMRAJESH?   "Someone who got a global function for this in OpenCart?".

Comment: @SVMRAJESH You should learn a lot about SO and reviewing. It is not enough to just see a *short answer*, *one line of code* to flag it - read also the question, switch on your brain and think...

Comment: Gavin I posted similar code until I realised this was OC2. It no longer works directly inside templates :(

Comment: @rjdown, I am currently working on OC2, and this is straight from one of the existing modules. I am using link just like it in my own custom template/module, and it works just fine. Perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Copy from controller/common/home/header.php

```
$this->load->language('common/header');
$data['text_home'] = $this->language->get('text_home');
```

and

```
$data['home'] = $this->url->link('common/home');
```

Add these to whichever controller needs them
Copy from header.tpl

```
href="<?php echo $home; ?>"
```

add to whichever template needs it.

Would that not cover SEO and link needs?